# How do I flip a mirrored object

Tags: mirror-modifier

I'm trying to recreate the V patterns in the image. After using the mirror modifier, it just mirrors it on the other axis. how do I flip the V to look like the image. Is there a way around it.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Cursor to World Origin
- Transform Pivot Point-3D Cursor
- Select v-pattern,
  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,duplicate;<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd>,60,rotate;<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,repeat the operation.

Comment: Thank you so much. It did work

Answer (score 8):

The instances of the 'V' logo are not reflections of one another; they are rotations. One way to produce this repetition is to use a rotational array: that is to say, an 'Object Offset' array, targeted on a rotated object. Here it's an Empty, rotated about Y by 60°.

[image]

Care has to be taken to line everything up: put all object origins aligned to the world, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> apply all scales, for this to work. If you parent the base and the logo to the Empty, as here, everything will move together, without falling apart.

**BTW**

While I was in your file, I had a go at your topology. In the Hex Base, the topology on the right will be much easier to work with than the topology on the left: it will *Bevel* and *Subdivide* well, and be much easier to select:

[image]

The 'V' logo has self-intersections in the corners. In Blender, you can achieve a cleanly mitred moulding by sweeping a **2D**  curve-profile around a **2D** path, in the path's 'Geometry' tab, 'Bevel' panel..

[image]

(My version still has too many vertices in the profile, and doesn't fully simulate yours, but it's still an illustration of the principle)

[image]

[image]

You'll find various incremental steps in the 'Backup' collection.

Comment: I should ask bogus questions with files attached so you can fix my topology :)

Comment: @Kuboå ..  XD ! ..and I should put up a few 'GN' q's for you to answer, of things I just happen to want converted to beautiful Graphic Design :)

Comment: Wow .. I really appreciate your comment. Did justice to the issue. Thank you. If you don't mind, could you put please put me through on how to do the 2D sweep curve. I'm new to blender so I really don't know how to work around what you described to clear the intersection.

Comment: Hi @MartinOtinga.. I don't mean to be obstructive..  we're already a bit off-topic on this question. My fault. SE isn't like a chat forum, so go ahead and post a new question, if you can't find an answer already, somewhere here.

Comment: Oh. Totally understand. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you want a rotation, not a reflection. However, if you do ever need a reflection use scale -1.